# Как сделать запрос на удаление из множества таблиц?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть 5 таблиц `Table1`, `Table2`, ...

В каждой таблице разное количество столбцов и строк, необходимо удалить из каждой таблицы строку, со значением `'buytoplay'`.

Дело в том, что названия столбцов, в которых присутствует это значение тоже разные, для `Table1` это `Column1`, для `Table2` это `Column2`.

Получится ли удалить все строки с таким значением из всех таблиц, и как это сделать?

Comment: Что-то я не припоминаю, чтобы SQL Server умел удалять из нескольких таблиц сразу... 5 таблиц - 5 отдельных запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', S.name, '.', T.name, ' WHERE ', C.name, ' = ''buytoplay''') AS "Script"
FROM sys.all_columns AS C
JOIN sys.types AS ST ON C.system_type_id = ST.system_type_id
JOIN sys.tables AS T ON C.object_id = T.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
WHERE ST.name IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar')
    AND T.name IN ('Table1', 'Table2', 'Table3')
```

После чего полученный результат упаковать в курсор и в цикле пройтись по курсору выполнив скрипт для каждого элемента курсора с помощью EXEC("Script").